# Using MediaCodec, is it possible to QueueInputBuffer to enquee a buffer that contains more than one NALU?

Tags: android, decode, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am decoding a live streaming of H264, it's working so far, but sometimes I got an accumulation of some H264 NAL units and I've seen that the input buffer I got from MediaCodec has enough room for more than one packet.

However when I try to add more than one in same input buffer it's not working, not sure why. Could someone guide me with this ? Or confirm if this is possible or not..